# How do I simplify this vim shortcut using variables?

Tags: variables, vim

I found and modified some vimrc code I found for commenting out the current line/block for vim:

```
"
" Commenting blocks
"
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java noremap <buffer> <Leader>c :s,^\(\s*\)[^// \t]\@=,\1// ,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
autocmd FileType sh,python  noremap <buffer> <Leader>c :s,^\(\s*\)[^# \t]\@=,\1# ,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
autocmd FileType vim        noremap <buffer> <Leader>c :s,^\(\s*\)[^\" \t]\@=,\1\" ,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj

autocmd Filetype c,cpp,java noremap <buffer> <Leader>u :s,^\(\s*\)// \s\@!,\1,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
autocmd Filetype sh,python  noremap <buffer> <Leader>u :s,^\(\s*\)# \s\@!,\1,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
autocmd Filetype vim        noremap <buffer> <Leader>u :s,^\(\s*\)\" \s\@!,\1,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
```

The original code used the `autocmd FileType` lines to set a variable to define the comment the line. It looked similar to this:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java let b:cmtldr=//
autocmd FileType sh,python  let b:cmtldr=#
autocmd FileType vim        let b:cmtldr=\"

noremap <buffer> <Leader>c :s,^\(\s*\)[^&b:cmtldr \t]\@=,\1&b:cmtldr ,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
```

But this didn't work for me, it just pasted in the literal string "&b:cmtldr" (I've also tried it without the &), so I changed it to the first block of code. However, my OCD won't let me let it be. I've done some searching for how to use variables in vim in this context, but nothing I tried helped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have two wrong syntaxes here:

1. `:let` is different from `:set`, so you have to use expressions here and lets should look like `let b:cmtldr="\""`.
2. There is no way you can put value of variable into regular expression and you have to use `\=` to put it into replacement string. Better to use `:execute` or `<C-r>` here:

   ```
   noremap \c :s,\v(\s*)(\V<C-r>=escape(b:cmdldr, '\,')<CR>\v|\s)@!,\=submatch(1).b:cmtldr,e<CR>:nohl<CR>zvj
   ```

   (I guess you did not actually mean having `<buffer>` here: it will enable commenting only for the first file you open from the command-line.)

---

Why reinvent the wheel, there are already plenty commenting plugins? I personally use NERD Commenter. It can be configured to use `\c` to comment, by default it uses `<Leader>cc` for comment in such way (there are more available options).

Comment: I'm customizing and learning vim at the same time. So searching/copying/writing this stuff has helped me a lot to learn vim the language. This one in particular, most search results do point me to a plugin, but I want the script so I can learn. So I've been hacking things together and trying to force it to work (as you can see :D). I'm sure I'll eventually switch to a plugin, but for now it's an exercise.